# Recursively extending a list in python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I've been trying to make my code more pythonic, and was wondering if there is a way to somehow make this one line.

```
w=[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] # just an example
for i in range(170):
    w.append(w[-2]^w[-3]^w[-4]^w[-8])
```

I tried to use lambda notation and got this, but it doesn't work for lengths greater than around 50.

```
[(lambda a:lambda v:a(a,v))(lambda s,x:1 if x==0 else (0 if x < 8 else s(s,x-2)^s(s,x-3)^s(s,x-4)^s(s, x-8)))(k) for k in range(170)]
```

I also tried recursing with lists:

```
(lambda n: (lambda f, n: f(f, n))(lambda f, n: f(f, n-1)+[f(f, n-1)[-2]^f(f, n-1)[-3]^f(f, n-1)[-4]^f(f, n-1)[-8]] if n > 0 else [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], n))(20)
```

I figure either of these would work with memoization, but I'm not sure how to do that inline if at all possible.

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: The first version is clearer and *way* more readable. Making it a one-liner will *not* make it more pythonic - it will make it a mess...

Comment: @timgeb I'm trying to calculate a round constant for a hash algorithm

Comment: @alfasin That's good to hear. Should I just leave it as is, or is there anything else that could clean it up any more?

Comment: You can leave it as is, it looks clear enough IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have is fine, but maybe turn it into a generator like:

```
def running_xor(w, n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield w[-2]^w[-3]^w[-4]^w[-8]

w.extend(running_xor(w, 170))
```

Comment: I would recommend against this, because it makes the order of execution less clear. For example, people have to remember that while slice-assignment would run the generator to completion before doing anything, `extend` adds each element before pulling the next one from the generator.

Comment: Fair point. I've been using too many coroutines, and now I can't stop!